# Show new form doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on this for some days. And now I have another problem. So I have this in my `zzz.cs`:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scraper zzz = new scraper();
    zzz.Show();
}
```

For 1 reason it doesnt want to open the other windows form that is called `scraper.cs`. My `zzz.cs` and `scraper.cs` have the same namespace. How can this not be working? and what is the fix?

EDIT:

The problem has been fixed, but now from login.cs it doesnt go to zzz.cs. My code for that is:

```
    MessageBox.Show("You are logged in successfully");
    zzz zzz = new zzz();
    zzz.Show();
    this.Close();
```

But that doesnt work now. How to fix that? Before it worked, now not anymore...

I tried it again. And I see that zzz.cs opens. And then direclty closes with code: 0. Here is my zzz.cs again:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Login
{
    public partial class zzz : Form
    {
        public static List<string> proxies { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> Links { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public static string path;
        public zzz()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logs.Items.Clear();
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                bool useproxies = true;
                Logs.Items.Add("Using proxies enabled!");
                scrape();
            }
            else
            {
                bool useproxies = false;
                Logs.Items.Add("Using proxies disabled!");
            }
            void scrape ()
            {
                int omg = proxyscraper();
            }
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public int proxyscraper()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Form1 aaa = new Form1();
            //aaa.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my inlogin.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Login
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        //Enter code here for your version of username and userpassword
        Login login = new Login("admin", "1234");


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //define local variables from the user inputs
            string user = nametxtbox.Text;
            string pass = pwdtxtbox.Text;
            //check if eligible to be logged in

            string login(string lol,string lel)
            {
                try
                {
                    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://SNIP/mama.php?user=" + lol + "&password=" + lel);
                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    return responseString;
                }
                catch
                {
                    string responseString = "NO";
                    return responseString;
                }
            }
            string wat = "YES";
            if (login(user, pass) == wat)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are logged in successfully");
                zzz aaa = new zzz();
                aaa.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                //show default login error message
                MessageBox.Show("Login Error!");
            }
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Howwww....

Comment: 1. What is the definition of `scraper`. 2. WinForms?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it, by setting a breakpoint into your Click-Method? Did you catch the event? Can you provide us the code of your classes.

Comment: Please read the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648) and apply that to your question with an [edit]. Also relevant: [mcve]

Comment: Does scraper inherit `Windows.Forms.Form`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson scraper is an Windows Form idk how to find that out

Comment: @Richard hope my edit can clear some things up.

Comment: @MartinBackasch hope my edit can clear some things up.

Comment: @rene hope my edit can clear some things up.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to compile your code? It should not did.

One reason is you are mixing the file name itselve and the class name. This are different names.

You have to create an instance of your class. In this case your Form by using its constructor.

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 aaa = new Form1()
    aaa.Show();
}
```

You can also rename your class `Form1` to `Scraper` and calling

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Scraper aaa = new Scraper()
    aaa.Show();
}
```

---

**Answering your EDIT**

You are using `zzz.Show()` which just opens a non-modal dialog of `zzz` and
executes the next method within the click method. which is `this.Close();`. This closes your current login form and this also closes your `zzz`. You may should use `zzz.ShowDialog();` to open `zzz`. Now the login dialog is 'waiting' until  your sxrapper dialog is closed. After that, the login screen closes itself by calling `this.Close();`.

I recommend that you change your application flow.
At first open your login Screen and after it closes with success you than opening your scraper.

As an example you can change your `Main` method in your `Program` class within the `Program.cs` file to:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var loginForm = new YourLoginDialog();
    var result = YourLoginDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Run(new Scraper());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
    }
}
```

---

In the case it is still not working:

Check if your `button3_Click_1` is wired to your `button3`.
There are many ways you can do this but the common ways you can do this is by using the Property Window of VisualStudio pressing `F4` selecting your `button3` and selecting the `bolt`/Event tab and chose your `button3_Click_1` method for the click event.
Or adding this following line to your constructor after the call of `InitializeComponent();`

```
this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click_1);
```

---

Answering your question from the comments above:

> scraper is an Windows Form idk how to find that out

Your `Scraper`(`Form1`) class inherits `System.Windows.Forms.Form` because of the **`: Form`** in the class definition.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // ...
}
```

*Maybe you should take a look at [Classes and Structs (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/index)*

Comment: @Justanotheryoutuber:I just want to check if you see my edit and if you need further assistance regarding my provided answer.